# Service in Silverlight application does not work when deployed

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, iis, iis-express

I've created a Silverlight application that uses a service. The service is defined in the web project in that solution. The silverlight application references it and uses it.
Everything works locally on my dev machine when I run the application in Visual Studio.

I note that the url im given from VS is: `http://localhost:50453/Default.htm`

But when I deploy this (by filesystem copy deploy option) the web page starts and it looks okey except that it seems to have a problem using the service. 
In the Silverlight application, if I look at the reference settings the url to the service is: `http://localhost:50453/SilverlightService.svc` and thats probably whats wrong, as the server that Im deploying to does not have a clue whats on port 50453.

So Im trying to change this port to 80 on my dev machine but Im out of luck. My web project does not have any property where I can change the port. Opened URL and URL is locked at `http://localhost:50453` :-/

How can I change the my dev environment to match the production environment with port 80?

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can change the web project's URL in project properties, but this is not a good solution because you'll get the same problems when accessing the SL application from a remote computer.

You need to set the service URL programmatically, like above:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client svc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
Uri serviceUri = new Uri(System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "Service1.svc");
svc.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
```

This solution uses the same URL that you are using to access the Silverlight Application.